# Allow null in jquery ui Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui

I'm currently getting this error.

*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'label' of null*

```
return $.extend( {}, item, {
            label: item.label || item.value,
            value: item.value || item.label
        } );
```

This line of code is the one giving me error in jquery-ui.

I know that the one causing the error is null values.
How could I allow it or if not prevent a null value to return as one of the result?

Here is mysql query:

```
 $get_company = "SELECT DISTINCT companies.company,companies.company_id
        FROM companies
        INNER JOIN target_details
        ON companies.company_id = target_details.company_id
        WHERE companies.company LIKE \"%$company%\"
        LIMIT 1500 OFFSET 10
        ";
        if($run_company = $conn->query($get_company)){
            while($row = $run_company->fetch_assoc()){
                $data[] = $row['company'].$row['company_id'];
            }

echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: you can set a condition by checking `(item.label === null) ? "null" : item.label` before assigning.

Comment: What exactly is `item`? Seems like that's `null`.

Comment: I dont know exactly.I'm just using this jquery autcomplete library.Its giving me and error from jquery-ui.js which doesn't exist in my project folder.

Comment: How do you generate `item`? Where do you get it from?

Comment: @Qirel Every time jquery autocomplete function is triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it be better "converts" null value to empty string in your query, like:

updated: You also need to change your loop.

```
$get_company = "SELECT DISTINCT NVL(companies.company, ''), NVL(companies.company_id, 0)
        FROM companies
        INNER JOIN target_details
        ON companies.company_id = target_details.company_id
        WHERE companies.company LIKE \"%$company%\"
        LIMIT 1500 OFFSET 10
        ";
        if($run_company = $conn->query($get_company)){
            while($row = $run_company->fetch_assoc()){
                $data_row["label"] = $row['company'].$row['company'];
                $data_row["value"] = $row['company'].$row['company_id'];
                array_push($data, $data_row);
            }

echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: You also have to change your code to adding records in `$data` array, see my updated answer, please.

Comment: Tried to reduce the limit to 500 to verify if its just a slow server response.I'm still not getting the results.

Comment: Your json should contains `label/value` attribute, I updated my code one more time. Probably the `NVL` is not necessary.

Comment: should I remove the nvl?

Comment: Yes, It never could be null

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
return $.extend( {}, item, {
            label: item.label ? item.label : item.value,
            value: item.value ? item.value : item.label
        } );
```

Comment: Should I do this in jquery-ui.js?